# Swift convert string to function name (#selector)

Tags: swift, string, function, selector

I made a function which receives a string. That string must be converted to a function name and then passed as a `#selector` parameter. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
func setFunctionWithTap(functionName: String) {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(functionName))
    ...
}
```

Could you please tell me if it is possible at all?

Comment: I believe the argument to a selector expression should now be a method or property name, as per [swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `Selector` [initializer that accepts a string](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/selector/1418671-init) instead:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(functionName))
```

Comment: You are welcome! ;) So you can mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Why are you using double parentheses around the function name?